# MacOS/Windows - How to extract specific .json file from multiple zips and renaming the .json file as folder it was extracted from

Tags: linux, windows, macintosh, zip, json

I am dealing with cuckoo sandbox exported data having report.json file under each Zip file

eg > 123456.zip each zip has the file in zipfile/reports/report.json

i have multiple zip files in a folder I want to have that zip files to be named as zipfilename.json.

ih have tried many ways but to fail

here's the code I am trying

```
    #! /bin/bash

mkdir -p "DESTDIR"
for i in *.zip ; do
         unzip "$i" $i/reports/report.json -d "DESTDIR"
         mv "DESTDIR/reports/report.json" "DESTDIR/$(basename "$i" .zip)_THEFILE"
done
```

All I get is this output showing that the file does not exist

```
(base) s@Sais-MBP Downloads % sh script.sh 
Archive:  1959098.zip
caution: filename not matched:  1959098.zip/reports/report.json
mv: rename DESTDIR/THEFILE to DESTDIR/1959098_THEFILE: No such file or directory
Archive:  1959100.zip
caution: filename not matched:  1959100.zip/reports/report.json
mv: rename DESTDIR/THEFILE to DESTDIR/1959100_THEFILE: No such file or directory
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I cannot make any progress for pas few days.

Answer (score 0):

Just some bugs in your shell script file. I fixed it as following code (you can use *bash -x* to debug & customize more if need)

```bsh
bash -x test.sh
```

***Notes:*** To run same code in **Windows & MacOS** I think you should use Linux WSL in Windows or replace **unzip** by **7z** in the following code:

```
#! /bin/bash
#
# save this file as test.sh
#
mkdir -p "DESTDIR"
for ZIPFILE in *.zip ; do
    NAME="${ZIPFILE%.*}"
    mkdir -p "DESTDIR/$NAME"
    unzip -j $ZIPFILE reports/report.json -d "DESTDIR/$NAME/"
    mv "DESTDIR/$NAME/report.json" "DESTDIR/$NAME.json"
done
```

Comment: Thank thank you, can't thank you enough for your time and passionate answer, thanks I was doing the whole thing wrong .

it works perfectly, will save me a lot of time by this smart script

Comment: i see you were a malware researcher,  I need to do malware analysis on Ransomware , ehere I have collected samples from virushare and performed individual upload to CUCKOO SANDBOX and got the report from it, now How do I merge the report.json files of different traits of Ransomware into one big Dataset, to perform the Machine Learning analysis on it ?

Comment: It's not hard to merge multiple report.json files into a big one, just write script to load json data, extract meaning data & group into a new dataset. I don't get your idea to use sandbox data to perform machine learning analysis (detect unknown ransomware, detect new variants ... ) but first I think you should learn the meaning information from cuckoo sandbox reports, extract them as feature to further research for your article.

Comment: yes, thank you for prompt reply, Yes I have to use the sandbox data to capture API calls and other meaningful data in order to detect unknown ransomware,

Is there a way we can learn meaning information from cuckoo sandbox reports?
i mean i have lot of data in Json but when creating a csv it create a 1 row *376 columns data.

Comment: @SaiKrishna Don't extract all keys, just focus on the "meaningful" values! For detecting ransomware, I think you could focus on file system activities (read, modify documents files) & Cryptography API Calling, also special activities which identified the ransomware families.

Comment: Thank you, i highly appreciate it